# Can't export function expression: "TypeError: xxx is not a function"

Tags: node.js, module

I was trying to follow basic guide on modules. I've created test_module.js

```
var textFunction = function() {
    console.log("text");
};

exports = textFunction;
```

And then I tried to use it in my app.js:

```
var textFunction = ('./test_module');

textFunction();
```

But I get an error:

```
 TypeError: textFunction is not a function
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or it was a very old guide?

PS: exports works only if I declare it like this:

```
exports.text = function() {
    console.log("text");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exports` is a local variable. Assigning to it won't change the exported value. You want to assign to `module.exports` directly:

```
module.exports = textFunction;
```

---

`module.exports` and `exports` initially refer to the same value (an object), but assigning to `exports` won't change `module.exports`, which is what counts. `exports` exists for convenience.

---

The other issue is that you are not properly requiring the module, but that may just be a typo. You should be doing

```
var textFunction = require('./test_module');
```

`var textFunction = ('./test_module');` just assigns the string `'./test_module'` to `textFunction` and we all know that strings are not functions.

Comment: Also use require('./test_module'); in your app.js