# Error: TypeError: helpers.sub_ele_index is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

Im calling a function named "sub_ele_index" from helpers file inside in my spec file but I got the issue as mentioned in title of this ticket

function body is (helpers.js):

```
exports.sub_ele_index = function (ele, tag, index){
var index_ele = ele.all(by.tagName(tag)).then(function(sub_elements){
    sub_elements.get(index);
});
return index_ele; }

This function called in spec.js as:
helpers.sub_ele_index($('#search_section'), 'li', 3);
```

Comment: You might want to assign to module.exports https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533409/cant-export-function-expression-typeerror-xxx-is-not-a-function. That being said, you should try to provide a reproducible piece of code. Here it's hard to say what you actually tried to solve it

Comment: please show your spec.js, especially the code block of  require at the head of spec.js, and check you not set another helpers as global variable like `global.helpers = xxx` in your code

Comment: Guys, That's all NOT related to exports or module.exports. This is very strange issue I have ever face.

Comment: When I put code from function "sub_ele_index " directly in my spec file then I face the issue as _Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"_

Answer (score 0):

Edit `helpers.js` and try this way, by this way you can export multiple function and can be used in another file.

```
    function sub_ele_index(ele, tag, index){
        var index_ele = ele.all(by.tagName(tag)).then(function(sub_elements){
            sub_elements.get(index);
        });
        return index_ele;
    }

    module.exports = { sub_ele_index }
```